Uploading the same working paper again after some years
In 2022, I uploaded a working paper to my university's working paper series. Since then, my experience has been somewhat unsatisfactory. Each time I needed to update the paper (which happened a couple of times), it took several weeks just to receive a response from those managing the series. Additionally, I feel that this platform offers less visibility compared to arXiv.
Now, in 2024, I have revised the paper and would like to upload the new version on arXiv. This would offer several advantages: (i) better control over updates, (ii) increased visibility, and (iii) easier citation and discoverability through platforms like Google Scholar.
My concern, however, is that arXiv will label the paper as "Author (2024)," whereas the correct citation should remain "Author (2022)." Could this affect citations? According to this post, Google Scholar may recognize it as a version of the original paper, not a new one. Still, I am worried that people who find the paper directly on arXiv might have difficulty realizing it is an updated version of the 2022 paper.

Wouldn’t your new version cite the previous working version?

@Aruralreader as far as I know, in my field (economics/econometrics) this is not common. New versions of the same paper replace older versions. I am aware of a couple of exceptions, but in that case the authorship changed (a new author was added). Also, how would I list the two versions in my cv? They share the same title and most (about 90%) of the contribution.

Do you mean for the purposes of the BibTeX citation generated by arXiv, for people manually citing the preprint, or for the purposes of Google Scholar?

I guess all of them. Releasing the new version as a new paper could also be seen as an attempt to boost my citation count in my field.

You can use the "comment" field in the arXiv submission process to say that this is a revision of the earlier version, and to say where the earlier version can be found.  You can also put this information in the paper itself, perhaps as a footnote.

I did not know that, that is a great suggestion! Thanks.

@AndreasBlass that should have been an answer :)

@Aruralreader, no need to cite as long as one replace the old version by a new version in arxiv because the identification number remains same. I have several versions of my articles in arxiv. One may add a comment in the the comment section. If one submit comparably major revision of some previous version in a "new identification number" or number then citation is required, otherwise not

@Learner yes but in my case the older version is not on arXiv, so the identification number would be "new."
